# How to turn a numpy array of MNIST to pytorch dataset/data

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist

On my ML class my teacher give us the MNIST data and let us train that using CNN.

The data is in a matlab `.mat` file: https://file.io/PS0CtiK2aom6

I managed to turn that into a numpy array of `(60000, 784)`

(60000 train data and each of them is 28x28=784)

Also the label (numbers `0-9`) is stored in a `(60000, 1)` array

Now I need to load it into a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`

but all I find on the internet is the dataset from pytorch itself `torchvision.datasets.MNIST`

and I am not sure if my data has the same shape and structure with pytorch's

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Also the label (numbers `0-9`) is stored in a `(60000, 1)` array

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** after you shared your dataset, you can use:

```
import scipy.io
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

def extract_dataset(mnist, name):
    dataset = [(images, np.repeat(int(target[len(name):]), len(images)))
            for target, images in mnist.items()
            if target.startswith(name)]
    X, y = list(zip(*train))
    X = torch.tensor(np.concatenate(X), dtype=torch.uint8)
    y = torch.tensor(np.concatenate(y), dtype=torch.uint8)
    return TensorDataset(X, y)

mnist = scipy.io.loadmat('mnist_all.mat')

train_ds = extract_dataset(mnist, 'train')
test_ds = extract_dataset(mnist, 'test')

train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Output:

```
# A batch of 32 images of 784 features (28x28) and 32 targets
>>> next(iter(train_dl))
[tensor([[0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         ...,
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=torch.uint8),
 tensor([1, 8, 5, 8, 0, 6, 5, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 3, 0, 8, 3, 4, 9, 0, 1, 8, 1, 8, 9,
         2, 6, 3, 8, 5, 4, 2, 2], dtype=torch.uint8)]
```

Input data:

```
>>> mnist
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNX86, Created on: Thu Nov 10 17:52:46 2005',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'train0': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test0': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train1': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test1': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train2': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test2': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train3': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test3': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train4': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test4': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train5': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test5': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train6': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test6': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train7': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test7': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train8': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test8': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train9': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test9': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)}
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use `DataLoader` with your data:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
```

However is not sufficient. Where are your targets?

I used the `mat` file from [here](https://github.com/ZZUTK/An-Example-of-CNN-on-MNIST-dataset/tree/master/DeepLearnToolbox_trimmed/data). Full example:

```
import scipy.io
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

mnist = scipy.io.loadmat('mnist_uint8.mat')

# Extract data from mat file and convert numpy array as tensor
X_train = torch.Tensor(mnist['train_x'])
y_train = torch.Tensor(mnist['train_y'])
X_test = torch.Tensor(mnist['test_x'])
y_test = torch.Tensor(mnist['test_y'])

# Create tensor datasets with features (X) and target (y)
train_ds = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
test_ds = TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

# Then make data loaders
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_dl = DataLoader(test_ds, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
```

Input data:

```
>>> mnist
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on: Wed Feb 22 20:38:11 2012',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'train_x': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'train_y': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
        ...,
        [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test_x': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8),
 'test_y': array([[0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)}
```

Comment: you can try this, this is my file: https://file.io/PS0CtiK2aom6